# Does broadcast reaches to all PCs in world (if we ignore timeout)?

Tags: broadcast

I am going through a networking book and it says that if we broadcast, message will reach to every hub/switch and will spread like tree. i.e. if we ignore timeout, broadcast will reach to all PCs in world?

if 'not', what stops switches from so? 
if 'yes' is it feasible?

Comment: When you say "going through" does that mean you're reading it?

Comment: yes. BTW, Is "going through' is wrong phrase for 'reading'?

Comment: it was sarcasm. hint: besides hubs and switches, there are routers, gateways, etc. what does the book say about them in regard to broadcasts?

Comment: the scope of a broadcast is limited to a broadcast domain.

Comment: Thanks, Pat answered well.

Comment: Can you mark his answer as the correct one then to attribute credit where it is due?

Answer (score 0):

If everything is a pure switch/hub with no processing or blocking rules or VLAN translations, then yes a broadcast packet would reach everything.

However, in the real world, this is not the case.  Most telecommunication providers prevent broadcast from going up into their network for security reasons.  Additionally, networks may be subdivided into virtual LANs (VLANS) preventing endpoints on one VLAN from communicating with endpoints on other VLANs.

This is even before routers and gateways enter the mix, each of which may have it's own broadcast blocking rules.

Comment: It means that broadcast message will reach my ISP. However ISP will kill that due to xyz reasons. Am I right?Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the ISP typically kills broadcast for one numerous reasons.  I am saying this with the assumption that you do not have anything that would block broadcast before it hits your connection to the ISP